# Exchange data between discord.py bot and example.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, discord.py

Please have a look [here](https://github.com/ngrhd/TallPy/blob/master/TallPy.py) and [here](https://github.com/ngrhd/TallPy/blob/master/discordpy.py):

In a really simple term, I wish to accept input from the bot and pass it onto 'x' (variable in TallPy.py) so that further evaluations are completed. And once it's is done, bot can print out the result from the TallPy.py to the Discord user. I'm really confused as to how to allow interchange of data between both of the files.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('.cr'):
       await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Enter the name of the creditor')
        for i in range(4):
            msg = await client.wait_for_message(')
            fmt = '{} left to go...'
            await client.send_message(message.channel, fmt.format(3 - i))

        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Good job!')
```

Thanks

What I want to achieve is to pass the msg variable into Tallpy.py x variable as follows:

```
for fixed, cl, due, overdue in zip(billfixed, billcl, billdue, billoverdue):
    #Getting it all lower case and then comparing
    if x.lower() == fixed.find('BILLPARTY').text.lower():

        date = fixed.find('BILLDATE').text
        ref= fixed.find('BILLREF').text
        party = fixed.find('BILLPARTY').text

        print(' * [Inv # {}] [Date {}] [Amt {}] [Due date {}] [Overdue by {} days]'.format(
        ref, date, cl.text, due.text, overdue.text
))

print('******************************************************************')
    else:
        print('Party name not found!')
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Please embed your code in your question rather than using links. You should also omit the token on line 21 of discordpy.py so that people can't hijack your bot.

Comment: Hello I've added the code and removed the API keys.

Comment: The solution here would be to use classes.  Wrap the stateful functionality of `TallPy` in a class and then create an instance of that class in `discordpy`.  (As an aside, these are kind of weird file names.)